# EF Core 3.0, Datetime timezone issue C#

Tags: c#, datetime, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-core-3.0

The datetime stored in the DB(postgresql) is with time zone(EST), while binding the value to code it is getting converted to system local time(IST), Even while trying to fetch it as string using convertors the value get converted to local time and display at string

Please help on how to ignore the Timezone in the  ModelBuilder

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<TblData>(entity =>
    {

        var converter = new ValueConverter<DateTime, DateTime>(
                   v => new DateTime(),
                   v => DateTimeOffset.Parse(v.ToString()).DateTime);

        var converter1 = new ValueConverter<string, DateTime>(
                   v => new DateTime(),
                   v => v.ToString());

        entity.Property(e => e.StartTime)
                               .HasColumnName("start_time")
                               .HasColumnType("timestamp(4) with time zone");
                               .HasConversion(converter);

        //both converters return value in localtime only
    }
}
```

a zone specific time conversion is not possible as the API layer is dealing with multiple timezone DB's and API is deployed in both Linux and windows server.

Please help !!!

Comment: Store datetime in db as UTC, and convert it on UI layer?

Comment: The date is not being converted to local time.  It is in UTC and uses you machine timezone to display in local time.  You always want to leave a date in UTC time especially if you are working across different timezones.  If you want to view the date in a different timezone then display using a different timezone do not convert.

Answer (score 0):

I usually set the TZ of the db user.

```
ALTER ROLE my_db_user IN DATABASE my_database
    SET "TimeZone" TO 'UTC';
```

Will this be of any use?